# Can you help me identify a broken potentiometer?

Tags: identification, potentiometer

I have a wierd potentiometer and i have search for a couple of days now but i can´t find it. Are anyone of you familiar with this one?

It´s broken so i need to replace it, and the axis trough it is used by the machine it sits in, so it has to be that type and form.

[image: Potentiometer name]

[image: Inside potentiometer]

[image: brandname]

Comment: Why do you need to "identify" it? Just measure it and use where appropriate.

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot to tell that its broken, so i need to replace it.

Comment: Are you able to measure it's resistance?

Comment: It might be custom-made for the machine manufacturer; potentiometers and transformers are commonly custom-made.  If the machine manufacturer doesn't have any, try a builder/integrator/repair that services that machine.

Comment: All I could find was an expired troutunderground.com listing for a part with a similar numbering scheme: Manufacturer: CMC 102 Model: 8847 Description: Precision Linear Variable Resistor CMC 102 MFR 03929 FCPST467-84.  There's little or no online information on "CMC", so it may be a manufacturer that was acquired or went out of business long ago.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the part that is broken is just a structural side support with a gap and the moving sides are not carbon coated.  This tells me it should be repairable with any suitable smooth replacement material and bonding adhesive.  A cellophane barrier to a flat strip can be used to remove and obtain a smooth surface.

[image]